# Can you use multiple Kinects with openni_launch?

Tags: ros, kinect, openni.launch, openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

We are using two kinects on our project and use openni_launch to access them. One program uses openni_launch openni.launch device_id:=#1 camera:=kinect1 and the other uses openni_launch openni.launch device_id:=#2 camera:=kinect2.

Both of these programs work separately but when we try to run both in parallel, the second kinect to launch doesn't respond. Is there a way to access multiple kinects at the same time?

Kind Regards,
Martin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49657/can-you-use-multiple-kinects-with-openni_launch?/) by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2012-12-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are your devices connected to the same USB hub? I had problems with that before.

Make sure that each Kinect is connected to an independent hub on the mother board.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2012-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on 2012-12-03**:
It appears that way from the outside. It's connected to a laptop and the two kinects are plugged in on opposing sides of the computer. Is there a way to check in the terminal?

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2012-12-03**:
You can take a look at the kernel messages when you plug in the Kinects. You should look for something like:

[239890.490560] usb 1-1.3: new high speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd

[239995.822980] usb 5-1.4: new high speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2012-12-03**:
If I am not mistaken, this means that one kinect is connected to the bus 1 and the other to bus 5

**Comment by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on 2012-12-04**:
Ahhh, yes. I checked out where the kinects were connected to and took this screenshot.([http://imgur.com/AAmUh](https://imgur.com/AAmUh)) I believe they are connected on a separate bus. Do you have any other ideas? Thanks for your help!

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2012-12-04**:
mmmm yeah, they seem connected to separate buses. Are you trying to visualize both point clouds with rviz? If you are, remember to set a tf transform between both kinects, otherwise you will not be able to visualize the point clouds.

**Comment by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on 2013-01-08**:
Thanks, Martin. We discovered that they were connected to two separate buses. Now the two kinects can run on the laptop, slowly, ha ha!

**Comment by [Asif](https://answers.ros.org/users/8441/asif/) on 2013-11-05**:
Dear MartinW, I've a request to you. I am going to start a bachelor thesis where i've to work on multiple kinect whish has to supported by open source program. can you please write here how you prepare your pc so that you could connect both the kinects. where can i code to chage the functions or develop the system? I highly appriciate your reply. Thank you.

**Comment by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on 2013-11-09**:
Hello Asif, I think you just need to make sure the Kinects are running on separate buses and then you can just run openni_launch with the different device IDs to run multiple Kinects. You should be able to do this fairly easily, just make sure you have enough ports and processing power on your comp!